# Why file uploaded to the server becomes read only?

Tags: file-upload, readonly

After uploading .xls file to the server it becomes read only. How to make it back read/write.

Comment: did you check the file permissions on the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check what `read only` really means in this case - is it lack of write permission (then use `chmod` to set one after all) or maybe your file is owned by someone else (which often happens on incorrectly configured hostings, where uploads are handled by `httpd`, not the user owning file hierarchy. If you got shell access do this:

```
$ ls -l
```

to list the files and see who owns it, then check what is your ownder id:

```
$ id
```

if these do not match, then you may need to reconfigure your server

Answer (score 2):

u can use chmod() php function.
simply type smthing like that:

```
chmod("/dir/file.xls", 0777);
```

more about it in documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php